# What is this seemingly sleeping creature in Rayman 3? (See attached screenshot)

Tags: rayman-3

Recently I was playing through Rayman 3, and I kept seeing these weird seemingly sleeping creatures here and there. Once walking up to them, they'd disappear and not seem to yield any points or such. I've attached a screenshot below wherein you can see one with a Z above their head, which to me would indicate that it sleeps. They always seem to have that Z until you approach them and they disappear. I've tried sticking out my tongue at them to see if that would do anything, but it appears not to. Besides, I've seen them before the part where you gain said ability, so it wouldn't make much sense if you had to use it to interact with them. For what it's worth I'm playing the Windows version of the game.

What are these creatures, and what are they for?

[image: Screenshot of the creature appearing in a stage in Rayman 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** get those, but you have to move sloooooowly.

[image]

They are called [Tribelle](https://raymanpc.com/wiki/en/Tribelle),  you have to approach it slowly or else it will just fly away. Touching them awards 250 points.

Also, since you asked, there is another creature in the game with similar mechanics.

The [Matuvu](https://raymanpc.com/wiki/en/Matuvu) are small green lizards. You may have noticed them hanging on walls, often somehow hidden.
Looking at them directly in first person mode will also award 250 points

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. The Tribelle link doesn't work due to that you added an extra pair of parenthesis but only removing 2 characters isn't enough to warrant an edit according to Stack Exchange. :(

Comment: Thanks for noticing, @Newbyte. Copy&Paste got wrong